# Laravel 5: Ajax post call failing with a resource

Tags: javascript, ajax, laravel-5

I have a Laravel 5 project running and I am trying to use an AJAX call to send some input data back to the server.  However, I keep running into Internal Service Errors.

I have a "user" resource that I am using for this:

This is the code:

routes.php:

```
Route::resource('user', 'UserController');
```

I have UserController.php and User.php models set up.

I have the Ajax call wrapped within a react.js function:

```
saveAndContinue: function(e) {
    e.preventDefault()

    // Get values via this.refs

    email = this.refs.email.getDOMNode().value

    request = $.ajax({ 
          url: "/user", 
          type: "post", success:function(data){
            this.setState({email: data})
          }, 
          data: {'email': email} ,beforeSend: function(data){console.log(data);} 
    });

  }
```

I am using the post /user route which should call the store function which I have in the controller:

```
public function store() {

        $v = Fan::validate(Input::all());

        $email = Input::get('email');

        if ( $v->passes() ) {  

            $user = new User;
            $user->email = Input::get('email');
            $user->save();

        }

        return $email;

    }
```

I have no idea why this isn't working.

### Edit

This is still not working:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="<?= csrf_token() ?>">

$.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});

request = $.ajax({ 
          url: "/user", 
          type: "post", success:function(data){
          }, 
          data: {'email': email} ,beforeSend: function(data){console.log(data);} 
    });
```

Comment: Any ideas from anyone?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly make a request you need to pass the csrf token to the laravel :)

```
     $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
        'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }
});
```

This will get the CSRF token from a header meta data tag and include it in the headers of each ajax request. Then you need to add the metadata and token into your Laravel templates, eg.

```
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="<?= csrf_token() ?>">
```

Hope this would help

Comment: why did Laravel make this so complicated in 5?  This was simple in 4.

Comment: I set this up and it is still not working.  See above in my question, what I am using.